# Which kind of curve is this

Tags: graphing-functions, curves, bezier-curve

Basically I'm currently using a software that edit curve and I was wondering which kind of interpolation it was using.

You have on point at `(0,0)` and another at `(1,1)`.

The middle point never changes `x` position but `y` changes when grabbing the point.

[image]

If you grab the middle point all the way up you get something like this.

[image]

It looks like an exponential function but I'm not sure about that because when you put the middle point at `(0.5,0.5)`. You get a perfect linear line from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)`

Comment: It is probably a [cubic Bézier curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch If it's a cubic bezier curve which means there are 2 controls points. But where do you decide to have the 2 controls points based on the middle point ?

Comment: What software? [Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) are very popular (flexible, rather intuitive) ways to approximste arbitrary curves, but there are many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is $f(t)=t^\alpha$, with $\alpha=\frac{\log y}{\log x}$.